# Flutter Image now showing properly/blue circle instead

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have a filePick function to select an image and display it as a profile picture (code bellow):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';


class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  PickedFile? pickedImage;
  late File imageFile;
  bool _load = true;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            final pickedFile =
                await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            setState(() {
              imageFile = File(pickedFile!.path);
              _load = false;
            });
          },
          child: _load == true
              ? Image.asset(
                  "images/null_pfp.png",
                )
              : CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 500,
                  backgroundImage: FileImage(imageFile),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But [as you can see in this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt7hA.gif), every time I select any image (jpg), it only displays this blue circle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there must be bug with "image_picker" ,
Please try to use : https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_for_web